# Reversing an array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

As the title says, I'd like to reverse an array made of objects in Javascript.

Example : `var x = [{"score":1},{"score":2},{"score":3}]`

To do so, I'm using the .reverse() method.

Now, let's say I write this code

```
console.log(x);
x.reverse();
console.log(x);
```

I'm expecting the console to show the array in the original order, then in a reversed order. However, It really shows both arrays in the reversed order.

How come ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`console.log()` takes into account whether a mutable object has changed before it has been printed on the screen. And as your process of **OUTPUT** -> **CHANGE** -> **OUTPUT** is almost plesiochronous, both outputs are the same.  You have to use a copy of x in order to get the prompt you need.

Try it this way:

```
// copy x
y = Object.assign({}, x);
console.log(y);

x.reverse();
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution if it answered your question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 46):

Best way to do that is `var y = [...x].reverse()`. See the snippet:

```js
var x = [{"score":1},{"score":2},{"score":3}]
var y = [...x].reverse();
console.log(x);
var y = [...x].reverse();
console.log(y);
```

Comment: To do what? ...

Comment: clone an array an reverse cloned one @JonasWilms

Comment: But ... that wasnt the question?

Comment: Sorry @JonasWilms , i think he want to reverse an array without changing original one...

Comment: `I'm expecting the console to show the array in the original order, then in a reversed order.  How come?` thats the question.

Answer (score -2):

According to MDN here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

The function `reverse()` is **destructive**

it means, the function change the original array, you have to create another variable if you want store the original array like this:

```
var array1 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
console.log('array1: ', array1);
// expected output: Array ['one', 'two', 'three']

var reversed = array1.reverse(); 
console.log('reversed: ', reversed);
// expected output: Array ['three', 'two', 'one']

/* Careful: reverse is destructive. It also changes
the original array */ 
console.log('array1: ', array1);
// expected output: Array ['three', 'two', 'one']
```

Comment: Thats not the question?